# I cannot do setText() for EditText which is in DialogBox

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog

The code is right there, from the line "edtInfoName.setText(userName)" I got the error which is I don't know why. The edtInfoName is in myDialog.xml. Please help me to figure out what is the problem.

```
itnInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText edtInfoName, edtInfoID, edtInfoPW;

                dialogView = (View) View.inflate(MyHome.this, R.layout.info_dialog, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyHome.this);
                dlg.setTitle("User Information");
                dlg.setView(dialogView);
                edtInfoName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInfoName);
                edtInfoID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInfoID);
                edtInfoPW = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInfoPW);
                edtInfoName.setText(userName);
                edtInfoID.setText(userID);
                edtInfoID.getFreezesText();
                edtInfoPW.getFreezesText();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should add dialogView . `edtInfoName = (EditText) dialogView .findViewById(R.id.edtInfoName);`

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this

```
itnInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edtInfoName, edtInfoID, edtInfoPW;

            dialogView = (View) View.inflate(MyHome.this, R.layout.info_dialog, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyHome.this);
            dlg.setTitle("User Information");
            dlg.setView(dialogView);
            edtInfoName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edtInfoName);
            edtInfoID = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edtInfoID);
            edtInfoPW = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edtInfoPW);
            edtInfoName.setText(userName);
            edtInfoID.setText(userID);
            edtInfoID.getFreezesText();
            edtInfoPW.getFreezesText();
        }
    });
```

You are trying to access edittext which is in info_dialog.xml so you need to access it via dialogview instance